# What is this conditional expectation equivalent to?

Tags: probability-theory

E[E[X|G]|G]

G is a sigma-field and X is G-Measurable.

What is this conditional expectation equivalent to?

Comment: $\mathbb E \left[X\vert G\right]$. Let $Y=\mathbb E\left[X\vert G\right]$, then by the law of total expectation $\mathbb E\left[Y\right]=\mathbb E\mathbb E\left[Y\vert G\right]$

Comment: I think, it  equal  $E(X|G)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if random variable $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable then we can take: $$\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=Y$$

Applying that on $Y=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ we find:$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]\mid \mathcal G]=\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]$$

Comment: What if X is not G-measurable?

Comment: @gnu.sean drhab's answer doesn't assume $X$ is $G$-measurable.  In fact, if $X$ is assumed to be $G$-measurable, then by the same logic, the answer is just $X$.

Comment: $X$ does not have to be $\mathcal G$-measurable. The point is that by definition $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable. That is used in my answer. As @Brian says: in the special case where $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable we can proceed the simplification by stating that also $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]=X$.